# Find smallest number Q whose product of digits is N

Tags: c

In the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000000000

int main()
{
    int n,temp,prod,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        temp=i;
        prod=1;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
           prod=prod*(temp%10);
           temp=temp/10;
        }
        if(prod==n)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is working. I need to input a number N and find the smallest integer Q such that the product of its digits is N. For example, if N=`10`, Q=`25`. I need to output -1 if there is no such number Q. Putting the following strip of code after the `if` code strip gives `-1` for all inputs

```
else
{
  printf("-1");
  break;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Fails to find smallest when `n == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `else` block inside the loop then it will fire as soon as any single guess fails. You want it to fire after *all* guesses have failed. That means the `-1` printout needs to be outside of the loop, after you've tried all the numbers and found all of them to be wrong.

But that means you can't use an `else` block. You'll need to use something else. How do you detect if the loop failed? One common way is to use a variable to track whether the loop succeeded or failed. For example, set `found = 0` before the loop starts, and inside the `if` statement when you've found a match set `found = 1`. Then after the loop ends, check the value of `found`. If it's still `0` then you didn't find a match and can output `-1`.

```
int found = 0;

for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
{
    // ...

    if (prod == n)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if (found == 0)   // could also be written: if (!found)
{
    printf("-1\n");
}
```

Comment: that too isnt working.giving same output as the code i did without any else strip.cant figure out why

Answer (score 1):

What happens when i == 1? You calculate prod = 1. And unless n = 1, the if-condition is false, and you print -1 and exit the loop.

Nice problem though. How would you go about finding the solution if n = 1,000,000,000?

Comment: probably by using `long int`? or maybe taking a group of digits as arrays and concatinating them ? not sure

Comment: i solved your case by making an array of all one digit prime factors of n and then finding the smallest permutation whose product is n.. works much faster than my old implementation

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to find one-digit factors of N and see which combination of products is minimum.